# Some question about set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In set theory, we have learned two sets are equal if and only if the have the same elements. Additionally I observe that we use the following  notation to descript set.

Ex : $\{x∈ \{1,2, 3\} | x>2\}$  or $\{x∈\{2,3,4\} : x+1=3\}$.

Actually, the above sets are equal.
It seems that for a set, do we just explain that what is its elements? and no other information, then we have already explicitly descript this set.

By extensionality axiom, we have learned that for set, we  just concerns its elements.

I do not know whether this idea is correct or wrong.

Comment: Ｏ　：{x∈ {1,2,3} ：　ｘ＝２　}

Comment: It's a good question. The reason we can use this notation (called set builder notation) is because of the axiom of specification, which specifies that given a set, and some set property (that evaluates every set to true or false), there exists a subset of the given set consisting only of those elements that satisfy the property.

Comment: Please edit the question to make it more legible and easier to understand what it is really about. Yes, the set is defined by its elements. Two sets are equal if and only if each element of one set belongs to the other. There is also the "set builder" notation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation ) of which you have shown some examples. What doubt have you got?

Comment: "Actually, the above sets are equal." - No, the first set is $\{3\}$ while the second set is $\{2\}$.